# GA - Inconsistencies in Total Number of Users and New Users

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

I have two puzzling cases in GA which I hope someone can enlighten me on.

1) Under **Audience**->**Overview**, why does the figure under **All Users** (Fig 1) changes when a new segment is added to the report (Fig 2)?

[image]
**(Fig 1)**

[image: Fig 2]
**(Fig 2)**

The new segment does not have to be new/returning visitor; the **All Users** figure changes on other segments as well. Note that the **Sessions** and **Pageviews** under the All Users segment do not change (correctly I believe).

Is this a bug in GA?

2) Using the same report with additional segments, why is the **Number of New Users** different from the **Number of Sessions by New Users** (Fig 3)?

[image: Fig 3]
(**Fig 3)**

[As explained by this post](https://www.e-nor.com/blog/google-analytics/google-analytics-new-labels-mystery-of-the-returning-visitors), a new user who visits the site a second time will be counted as a returning visitor, so his second and succeeding sessions should now be counted as sessions being done by a returning visitor.

Doesn't this mean that the number of new users should be the same as the number of sessions done by new users? Are there exceptions (perhaps using a different browser or device) that will skew the results?

Thanks

Comment: Some reports are precalculated. If you add segments reports are re-calculated on the fly. I assume that ad-hoc reports do not use quite the same sample than precalculated reports, so the numbers come out a little different.

Comment: Thanks Eike.  That behavior is confusing really.  Even changing the order of segments generates new result, though the variances are small (plus or minus 1 or 2 if I remember correctly in my case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 per Eike's comment - including segments causes the numbers to be recalculated and may be slightly different from the precalculated report numbers.

## 2 is caused by sessions overlapping midnight.  GA creates new sessions, and they have the same user and 'New User' flag associated with them, so it looks like 2 sessions with 'New User' settings but it is only 1 user.

Comment: Thanks Mike. 1) So do we prefer the view with total users and segments  than just the view with the total users since the former is realtime and more updated?  What puzzles me also is why the recalculated and precalculated figures are not the same when the time frame is for last year.  If the end point is more recent, say today, then perhaps we have to wait a day or two (accounting also for time differences) for GA to finish its calculations.  But if the end point is last year, then there's no new data coming in and its just a matter of drilling up and down the same set of data.

Comment: For 2),  do the new sessions happen every midnight for the defined time period?  So in this scenario the New User figure is more correct than the New Sessions figure?  Have up discovered this thru observation yourself or have you read this somewhere else?  Thanks again

Comment: As Eike suggested, if GA goes back and recalculates, there might be some sampling effect, even if it is not reported. Details of GA server operations is a mystery.

Comment: For 2) , as I have read in various places over time. The Users metric for sessions with User Type = New Visitor would be the most accurate.

Comment: For 1), I just verified this actually does happen. 1 visit (user) crossing over midnight gets turned into 2 sessions, each tagged as User Type = New Visitor. % New Users is based on Sessions, which is why I recommend using the Users metric.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, is 20,513 the correct count in Fig 2?  On the other hand, in the report Behavior->New vs Returning, the number of New Users (4th column) seems to equal the number of sessions for New Users (20,540)

Comment: 20,513 would be the most accurate number. The other number is the count of Sessions which are tagged as New Users, and they may contain duplication because of the midnight-crossing behavior.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks Mike!  Kinda miss our previous log analytics software where we can easily verify every stat by looking at the logs directly.